# Value is getting removed from Javascript map

Tags: lightning

Hello I have one lightning component where I have questions and answers from two different objects which are related master-detail. I have built a javascript map to hold Selected radio button value and parent question id. It works well but in one scenario it breaks.

Two questions have same Radio options for example:

Question 1
Yes
No

Question 2

Yes 
No

Question 3

Not Good
Good

When i select different values for each Question 1 and Question 2, it works well but when i select same values for question 1 and question 2 it removes the other value and shows only one value.

For example:

If i select Yes for Question 1 and No for Question 2 it holds both values but If i select either yes for both questions or No for both questions, it holds only one value and removes the other value. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is a collection of elements where each element is stored as a Key, Value pair. If the `key` is repeated, it will override the existing element with the updated one.

As you are holding the answers as `Key` in the `Map`, and if the answer is repeated, it will override the existing value in the `Map`. This is the reason, you are getting only two values when you are selecting the same answers. So, this is working as per design.

You can change the `Map` structure to hold `QuestionId` (which I suppose from the screenshot would be unique) as the `Key` and Answer as the `value`, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Vijay It helped!